# Interface (two methods, different return types depending on class) Java

Tags: java, interface

Any class that extends an interface must implement the methods declared in the interface. Not sure if this is possible but what I want to do is the following :

```
interface test {
   ____ get();
}

class A extends test {
  int val;

  A(int x) {
    val = x;
  }

  int get() {
    return Val;
  } 


  class B extends test {
  String val;

  B(String x) {
    val = x;
  }

  String get() {
    return Val;
  }
```

Is it possible to have a method signature that is able to return two different data types?

Comment: Not in Java. But e.g. Haskell has this capability, i.e. to overload on the return type.

Comment: In Java, the signature is absolute and must be followed exactly as declared

Answer (score 25):

Not exactly like that but you can get close with a generic type parameter.

```
interface Test<T> {
    T get();
}

class A implements Test<Integer> {
    int val;

    A(int x) {
        val = x;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer get() {
        return val;
    }
}

class B implements Test<String> {
    String val;

    B(String x) {
        val = x;
    }

    @Override
    public String get() {
        return val;
    }
}
```

As you can see, you're bound to use `Integer` because generics don't work with primitives.

Also note, those 2 versions of the same interface are essentially 2 different interfaces now.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. The interface serves as a "binding contact" of the signatures that are available.

If you want you can have the function return an `Object` and by that allow different implementations to return values of different types, but:

1. It must be references, not primitives.
2. You loose type safety at the call site.

Comment: See zapl's answer.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - we all know generics, but that's not the same interface anymore, and zapi even noted that in the answer. The correct answer is that there is no way to do that with a **single interface**.

Comment: @Amit Technically, `get()` could just return `Object`, but that's probably not good advice to give to someone who's new to generics :)

Comment: @Ownaginatious - question is not about generics and neither is my answer.

Comment: @Amit Judging from all the syntax mistakes in the poster's question, he/she may not know about generics and that may be better suited for whatever they're trying to solve. I +1'd your answer because after the edits, it is the most technically correct, and isn't a repeat of the current top answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with generics, but it's not enforced at runtime. You should also be using `implements` to implement an interface in a class, rather than `extends`.

```
interface Test<T> {
   T get();
}

class A implements Test<Integer> {
    int val;

    A(int x) {
        val = x;
    }

    @Override
    Integer get() {
       return Val;
    } 

}

class B implements Test<String> {
    String val;

    B(String x) {
       val = x;
    }

    @Override
    String get() {
        return Val;
    }
}
```

Generics only apply to classes, so you're forced to use `Integer` rather than `int` as the return type.

Answer (score 0):

This compiles, although I'm not sure I recommend doing things this way:

```
interface test {
   Object get();
}

class A implements test {
  int val;

  public A(int x) {
    val = x;
  }

  public Integer get() {
    return val;
  } 
}

class B implements test {
  String val;

  public B(String x) {
    val = x;
  }

  public String get() {
    return val;
  } 
}
```

It's legal in Java to override a method using a return type that is a *subclass* of the original method's return type.  This is called "covariance".  It only works on return types, not on parameters.  Note that to get this to compile, I had to make `get` in class `A` return `Integer` and not `int`.  Also: use `implements`, not `extends`, when implementing an interface; and make sure that you use the correct letter case when referring to variables (`Val` in your posted code does not work).

As I said, I'm not sure I recommend this, because in any code that declares something of type `test`, the result of `get()` is an `Object`, which you will have to cast to something else to make it useful.  If possible, generics should be used instead.  However, it's not always possible.  I would think carefully about your design before writing an interface like this.  It may be that an interface isn't really what you want.  However, I can't tell without more details about what you're trying to accomplish.